# Gerar dinamicamente JSON a partir de formulario android

Tags: java, android, json

**Contexto:**
Tenho um app Cordova que há formulários de fichas do SUS com mais de 30 campos que é enviado para o servidor através de JSON. Estou construindo um APP nativo android para a mesma função;

**Problema:**
Preciso mapear os campos (EditText, Spinner, CheckBox e RadioButtons) em objetos JSON, no cordova tem a facilidade do JQuery onde eu pego todos os campos do formulario atraves da função $('form') e envio para uma função que a partir do tipo de input mapea no JSON ("input.name", "input.value"), já no Java eu não tenho essa facilidade e por este motivo estou mapeando campo a campo e obtendo os "values" de cada campo do banco de dados pois os values que devem estar no JSON são diferentes dos mostrados para a selação do usuario.

**Objetivo:** 
há alguma biblioteca ou uma maneira de pegar dinamicamente todos os campos to formulario no android e fazer uma função dinamica que apartir da resposta do instanceof de cada campo eu mapeie o JSON corretamente?

Amostra do codigo de mapeamento dos inputs para JSON:

```
/*
 * Geração do JSON apartir do form.
 * A principio é tratado campo por campo pela complexidade em mapear as labels
 * de RadioGroup e Spinner nos valores requeridos pelo sistema de exportação.
 */
private JSONObject formToJSON(View rootView) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

    /**
     * Primeira parte
     */
    //Mapeando EditTexts no JSON
    //Nome Paciente
    jsonObj.put(cadNome.getTag().toString(), cadNome.getText().toString());

    //Data Nascimento
    jsonObj.put(cadDataNasc.getTag().toString(), cadDataNasc.getText().toString());

    //Sexo
    String sexo =  rootView.findViewById(cadRadGroupSexo.getCheckedRadioButtonId()).getTag().toString();
    jsonObj.put(cadRadGroupSexo.getTag().toString(), sexo);

    //Tipo Sanguineo
    String tipoSanguineo =  cadTipoSanguineo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //jsonObj.put(cadRadGroupSexo.getTag().toString(), sexo);
    //TODO obter id do tipo no banco de dados e inserir no JSON

    //Nome da Mãe
    jsonObj.put(cadNomeMae.getTag().toString(), cadNomeMae.getText().toString());

    //Check box desconhece nome pai
    //TODO ver como se obtem o valor do checkbox e inserir de forma correta no JSON

    //Nome pai
    jsonObj.put(cadNomePai.getTag().toString(), cadNomePai.getText().toString());

    /**
     * Segunda parte
     */
    //E-mail
    jsonObj.put(cadEmail.getTag().toString(), cadEmail.getText().toString());

    //Nacionalidade
    String nacionalidade = rootView.findViewById(cadRadGroupNac.getCheckedRadioButtonId()).getTag().toString();
    jsonObj.put(cadRadGroupNac.getTag().toString(), nacionalidade);

    //Pais de nascimento
    String paisNascimento =  cadPaisNasc.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //jsonObj.put(cadPaisNasc.getTag().toString(), );
    //TODO obter id do paisNasc no banco de dados e inserir no JSON

    //Data naturalização
    jsonObj.put(cadDataNatur.getTag().toString(), cadDataNatur.getText().toString());

    //Portaria naturalização
    jsonObj.put(cadPortariaNatu.getTag().toString(), cadPortariaNatu.getText().toString());

    //Data entrada no brasil
    jsonObj.put(cadDataEntrada.getTag().toString(), cadDataEntrada.getText().toString());

    //Estado
    String estado = cadEstado.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //TODO obter id do estado no banco de dados e inserir no JSON

    //Municipio de nascimento
    jsonObj.put(cadMunicipioNasc.getTag().toString(), cadMunicipioNasc.getText().toString());

    //Tipo de documento
    String tipoDoc = cadTipoDoc.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //TODO obter id do Tipo de documento no banco de dados e inserir no JSON

    //Documento
    jsonObj.put(cadDocumento.getTag().toString(), cadDocumento.getText().toString());

    //CNS
    jsonObj.put(cadCns.getTag().toString(),cadCns.getText().toString());

    //Prontuario
    jsonObj.put(cadProntuario.getTag().toString(), cadProntuario.getText().toString());

    //CPF
    jsonObj.put(cadCpf.getTag().toString(), cadCpf.getText().toString());

    //RG
    jsonObj.put(cadRg.getTag().toString(), cadRg.getText().toString());

    //CTPS
    jsonObj.put(cadCtps.getTag().toString(), cadCtps.getText().toString());

    //Raca/Cor
    String racaCor = cadRacaCor.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //TODO obter id do Raca/Cor no banco de dados e inserir no JSON


    return null;
}
```

Template de uma função que seria dinamica que procuro:

```
public void formToJson(Inputs input){
    if(input instanceof EditText){
        //Executo o mepeamento de EditText
    }
    if(input instanceof Spinner){
        //Executo o mapeamento de Spinner
    }
    //Assim por diante
}
```

Comment: Sim, existem bibliotecas que vão te auxiliar. Recomendo o [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) . Você pode criar um objeto, genérico, se preferir, para o formulário e o retrofit irá fazer o parse dos dados JSON. Basta vc trazer os objetos para os campos, que vc deseja carregar na Activity.

Comment: Uma outra opção poderia ser o [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson). Você criaria uma classe que representa seu json, com todos os campos necessários. Na activity, você pode instanciar esse objeto e ir setando as propriedades dele com os valores dos componentes (EditText etc.). No fim, em uma linha de código, o GSON monta para você o Json. [Aqui](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html) um tutorial que pode ser útil.

Comment: Obrigado pelos comentários eu irei testar as duas ferramentas, a que ficar melhor eu marco como importante ou se quiserem fazer uma resposta sobre isso eu irei marcar como respondido a que me atender melhor! Obrigado!